# Parsing SQLite Database Schema in sqlitedb file?

Tags: sqlite, parsing

I wrote a program for parsing SQLite file, i can parse all data from b-tree pages to record, column & values but i need to parse schema of tables, i found something like **database schema stored in page 1 (root page)** and i can see it with `Hex Editor`, and i found structure of `sqlite_master`, i read it exact as explain in http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

I want to know how can i found the first byte of sqlite_master table in db file, how can i detect starting byte of schema? is there anything related in SQLite DB Header?

**Edit 1 (more info):**

For example:
i opened sqlite db with hex editor, (if you check my page size is 4096 bytes and i marked page header in image):
[image]

i marked root page header that start with 05 means `the page is an interior table b-tree page` and please check **B-tree Page Header Format (http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html)** and its have 5 cells that you can see it with this cell pointers array: 0FFB, 0FF6, 0FF1, 0FEC, 0FE7 (that start after ending header) and all cells have 5 bytes and start from 0FE7 then the schema that you can see it in picture ( in text part ) start from 232~240 and i check other dbs and schema in different place...

**Edit 2:**

You can download Example File from https://www.dropbox.com/s/lanky02kneyb74w/31bb7ba8914766d4ba40d6dfb6113c8b614be442

**Edit 3:**

In my file you can see

```
$ hexdump -C 31bb7ba8914766d4ba40d6dfb6113c8b614be442

00000000  53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66  6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00  |SQLite format 3.|
00000010  10 00 02 02 00 40 20 20  00 00 00 02 00 00 00 3f  |.....@  .......?|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 47 00 00 00 04  |...........G....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  |................|
00000060  00 2d e2 25 05 00 00 00  05 0f e7 00 00 00 00 3d  |.-.%...........=|
00000070  0f fb 0f f6 0f f1 0f ec  0f e7 08 7f 07 9d 08 3c  |...............<|
00000080  07 01 06 22 05 92 04 fe  03 fc 04 c1 03 4d 02 b8  |...".........M..|
00000090  02 0a 02 75 01 32 01 c7  00 e9 00 e9 00 00 00 00  |...u.2..........|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 47 18 06 17 5b 35 01  |.........G...[5.|
000000f0  00 69 6e 64 65 78 73 71  6c 69 74 65 5f 61 75 74  |.indexsqlite_aut|
00000100  6f 69 6e 64 65 78 5f 41  42 4d 75 6c 74 69 56 61  |oindex_ABMultiVa|
00000110  6c 75 65 45 6e 74 72 79  4b 65 79 5f 31 41 42 4d  |lueEntryKey_1ABM|
00000120  75 6c 74 69 56 61 6c 75  65 45 6e 74 72 79 4b 65  |ultiValueEntryKe|

Page Header ( offset 64)

05          <- interior table b-tree page
0000        <- Byte offset into the page of the first freeblock
0005        <- Number of cells on this page
0FE7        <- Offset to the first byte of the cell content area
00          <- Number of fragmented free bytes
0000003D    (61) <- The right-most pointer

Cell Array Pointers & Cell Contents:
(Table Interior Cell Format)

Cell Pointer| Page number of left child | Rowid
------------|---------------------------|-------
0FFB        | 0000001A      (26)        | 15
0FF6        | 0000001C      (28)        | 2D
0FF1        | 00000031      (49)        | 3C
0FEC        | 00000039      (57)        | 48
0FE7        | 0000003C      (60)        | 4C     <- equal to (Offset to the first byte of the cell content area) in page header
```

Comment: And what specific problem do you have with that file?

Comment: @CL. tanx so much dude for try to solve my prb, if you remember me you follow me to wrote SQLite parser for extract data and recover deleted records (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628240/how-can-i-recover-deleted-data-from-sqlite), i wrote it and its works fine and extract all values but now, i just want to load schema of table, how can i found schema?, if you read page 1 header or cell pointer array (root page) you can`t find offset of schema, and can`t load sqlite_master table..

Comment: @CL., please show me how can you find schema offset in sqlite db file if first table be an `interior table b-tree page` like my file ..!?

Comment: Updated the answer. The schema is stored in the column `sql` of the `sqlite_master` table.

Answer (score 4):

I realize your question was asked over a year ago and you probably resolved it, but I would like to submit an answer in case anyone else has this same question.  I was in the same situation as you, Mehdi.  I wanted to read a SQLite database file, and was looking for the master table / schema.  It appeared to be in page 1, but the header was not pointing to it.  There were two reasons for my confusion.

(1) There was a lot of "dead" data in my SQLite database file that was not being used.  I believe as the database was created and grew, the location of the actual active data moved, and the old location was not overwritten with zeros.  Doing a search for some of the "CREATE TABLE" statements found multiple results in different locations of the file.  I later determined the actual schema was split up and located on pages 18, 10, and 8 (which the page 1 interior table pointed to). I would have detected this earlier, if not for reason #2.

(2) I had miscalculated the byte position of the page number, which confused me.  Where p = page #, and s = page size, I thought it was [p * s] .... but actually it's [(p-1) * s] (except for page 1 which starts at byte 100). In other words, I thought the page numbering started at zero instead of 1.

As an additional note, I believe the http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html page is missing some vital info. Specifically, it doesn't explain where the "root page" number is in the schema table (it's in field 4).  I couldn't find this information on the sqlite.org page.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is right or not, but good answer either way.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to says in [section 2.6](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master):

> Page 1 of a database file is the root page of a table b-tree that holds a special table named "sqlite_master"

and in [section 1.5](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#btree):

> A b-tree page is divided into regions in the following order:
>
> 1. The 100-byte database file header (found on page 1 only)
> 2. The 8 or 12 byte b-tree page header …

---

For example, with this database:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db "create table hello(world);"
$ hexdump -C test.db 
00000000  53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66  6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00  |SQLite format 3.|
00000010  04 00 01 01 00 40 20 20  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02  |.....@  ........|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 04  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |................|
00000060  00 2d e6 03 0d 00 00 00  01 03 cf 00 03 cf 00 00  |.-æ.......Ï..Ï..|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000003c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2f  |.............../|
000003d0  01 06 17 17 17 01 3f 74  61 62 6c 65 68 65 6c 6c  |......?tablehell|
000003e0  6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 02 43  52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41  |ohello.CREATE TA|
000003f0  42 4c 45 20 68 65 6c 6c  6f 28 77 6f 72 6c 64 29  |BLE hello(world)|
00000400  0d 00 00 00 00 04 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

... the page header at offset 0x64 has these values:

- `0d`: page is a leaf table b-tree page
- `0000`: freeblock offset
- `0001`: number of cells
- `03cf`: offset of cell content
- `00`: fragmented free bytes
- `03cf`: first cell pointer

And at offset `3cf`, you have a standard table b-tree leaf cell, containing the only row of the `sqlite_master` table:

```
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
type        name        tbl_name    rootpage    sql                      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------------------------
table       hello       hello       2           CREATE TABLE hello(world)
```

Comment: tanx for helping me, i read it but in page header you can not find any thing about schema and cell pointers array not help to me.. schema placed in unallocated area.. please check Edit 1, tanx again

Comment: i gave upvote, but please check in my db file, its start with interior table b tree page.. please check it ( its a contact db of iphone, you can open it with SQLite Manager ).. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lanky02kneyb74w/31bb7ba8914766d4ba40d6dfb6113c8b614be442

Comment: please check link and help me about this file... that start with interior b-tree page.

Comment: tanx cl but please show me on my file example or any sqlite db that start with b-tree table interior .. please tell to me how can you find schema offset when root page is b-tree interior table..? & tanx for help.